# Hebrew Diacritics Positioning Error In Word Processor

Tags: fonts, font-design, font-forge, spacing

I'm using FontForge to create a Hebrew font that supports advanced diacritics, i.e. distinguishes between sheva naḥ and dagesh ḥazaq/qal. The Unicode symbols for sheva and dagesh represent the latter, while an unassigned Unicode space is used for the former (I also expanded the glyphs' stroke width to make the distinction visible).
Within each set, both marks use the exact same anchors, so in theory, they should be positioned at the same place. The metrics window in FontForge shows what it's *supposed* to look like:
[image: Metrics Window]
But my word processor (LibreOffice) misplaces the custom characters:
[image: LibreOffice]
I already made sure the problem isn't caused by the increased stroke thickness, and all four glyphs are assigned to the "Mark" class in the glyph info. Moving the unassigned characters across Unicode blocks (from "Hebrew" to "Alphabetical Presentation Forms" or into the "Private Use Area") didn't help, either.

EDIT: Assigning these glyphs a location defined by Unicode as a Hebrew mark gets rid of the problem. But placing it in "Combining Diacritical Marks" doesn't. It seems like all code points, with a few exceptions, are hardcoded to be treated as a letter, not a mark, in LibreOffice. Any idea how that works and how to override it (as I don't want to use an "incorrect" Unicode character for my custom glyphs)?